# Как определить привилегию юзера в Django

Tags: python, django

Я собираюсь создать электронный журнал для школы. Но не могу определить привилегию юзера в views.py 
Как определить пользователя (учитель, ученик, родитель), и загрузить соответствующие функции

Comment: Смотря как эти привилегии заданы. Вы распределили пользователей по соответствующим группам? Создали определённые права доступа и наделили ими определённых пользователей? Переопределили стандартную модель пользователя и добавили в неё свойство определяющее тип пользователя?